# How to create minimalistic map for ios app

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, mapkit, mkmapview

How can I implement the same map as on screenshot?

I found out about custom overlays for `MKMapView` but I'm not sure it's a good way for change all maps.

Probably you have some ideas about this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with if there is any better solution to achieve this.
I am using Overlays as you have mentioned in your question.

You can customize the Overlay with your own beautiful style at https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

You will get the JSON for the customization, include your App Key and you are ready to use in your App.

In your App

```
import GoogleMaps

@IBOutlet weak var viewMap: GMSMapView!
public let kMapStyle = "[{\"elementType\": \"geometry\", \"stylers\": [ { \"color\": \"#f5f5f5\" } ] },{\"elementType\": \"labels.icon\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"on\"}]},{\"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#616161\"}]},{\"elementType\": \"labels.text.stroke\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#f5f5f5\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"administrative.land_parcel\",\"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#bdbdbd\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"poi\",\"elementType\": \"geometry\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#eeeeee\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"poi\",\"featureType\":\"poi.business\",\"stylers\": [{\"visibility\": \"on\"}],\"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#757575\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"poi.park\",\"elementType\": \"geometry\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#e5e5e5\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"poi.park\",\"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#9e9e9e\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"road\",\"elementType\": \"geometry\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#ffffff\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"road.arterial\",\"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#757575\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"road.highway\",\"elementType\": \"geometry\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#dadada\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"road.highway\",\"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#616161\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"road.local\",\"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#9e9e9e\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"transit.line\",\"elementType\": \"geometry\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#e5e5e5\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"transit.station\",\"elementType\": \"geometry\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#eeeeee\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"water\",\"elementType\": \"geometry\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#c9c9c9\"}]},{\"featureType\": \"water\",\"elementType\": \"labels.text.fill\",\"stylers\": [{\"color\": \"#9e9e9e\"}]}]"
//YOUR JSON FOR STYLE

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    do {
        viewMap.mapStyle = try GMSMapStyle(jsonString: kMapStyle)
    } catch {
        NSLog("One or more of the map styles failed to load. \(error)")
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this helps or you face any other issue while implementation.